# Dynamic invocation of WSDL 2.0 described service

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws, cxf

I am building a system in Java/Groovy that involves dynamic invocation of Web services. I use JAX-WS to invoke a service with a WSDL 1.1 interface, but I could not find any helpful information about how one would go about to implement DII for WSDL 2.0 descriptions.

**Could anyone of you point me in the right direction about dynamic invocation for Web services with WSDL 2.0 interfaces?**

Thanks in advance,
moxn

PS: This [post on a mailing list](http://markmail.org/message/skyib6tearix2xpg#query:jaxws%20wsdl%202.0+page:1+mid:ifzg5kq55ugkckcp+state:results) suggests that JAX-WS does not support WSDL 2.0. What other options do I have then? Does maybe Apache CXF come with support for WSDL 2.0?

EDIT: I just tried to dynamically invoke a WSDL 2.0 Web service with JAX-WS but got the WSDL exception `faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions'.` Looks like JAX-WS DII does really not work with WSDL 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache CXF only support wsdl 1.1, but WSo2 has support for wsdl 2.0 and might have what you are looking for. It uses Axis 2 i believe.

Comment: Hmm, apparently is AXIOM the preferred way to create dynamic invocations of WSDL 2.0 services in Axis 2. But it doesn't look as straightforward as the DII support in JAX-WS :(

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried, but Axis 2.0 claims that WSDL 2.0 is supported (on the [main page](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/)).

So if you use XML Mapping tools compatible with the Axis2 API, it should work. Here are some compatible XML Mapping tools :

- [ADB](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_2/adb/adb-howto.html) ( + Axis2)
- [XmlBeans](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/1_1_1/userguide-creatingclients-xmlbeans.html) ( + Axis2)

Note: Apache-CXF does not support WSDL 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for anwering. Axis 2.0 does indeed support WSDL 2.0. But if I'm not mistaken are ADB and XmlBeans used only to create Stubs/Proxies from WSDL or XSD files, which is unfortunately not what I need. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Yes, they are "XML Mappers" usually used with Axis2. After another analyse of theses APIs, they don't generate theses mapping "on the fly".